# SSRS 2016 Object Alignment is off on Server Render

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm trying to create floor plan maps with data interspersed throughout the map. When I'm in design mode AND preview mode in Visual Studio, the report appears with objects perfectly lined up as I expect. However, when I publish to the server and run on the server, object alignment is off. I can't find anything related to my issue or how to tell it I want things placed in a specific location when running on the server. I'm already using Rectangles to contain elements but that doesn't seem to help. Images below show what I'm running in to. I have Admin access to the server so if I need to make changes there, I can. I'm happy to share my .RDL file if I can figure out how to upload it.

Any ideas to fix this infuriating problem would be welcome.

Design mode:
[image]

Preview mode:
[image]

Render on the server:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSRS is pretty bad for something like this that requires precise locations.  Not really a setting you can adjust to fix it, it's just not meant for this type of application.  Additionally, the report manager(in browser) always messes up the formatting.  I always recommend exporting the report to a .pdf to see how it looks before finalizing anything.  With that said, if this is client facing -- I'd suggest adapting this to use a .pdf viewer or just exports and opens a .pdf.  Cleans things up and gives you a uniform result every time.

Another thing I could suggest if you insist on using SSRS would be to re-do the report using Tablixes as opposed to rectangles.  These tend to hold shape better and you could do some creative borders to produce a similar result.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I pretty much settled on this being the case but was hoping for another option like editing the CSS. Tablix idea is interesting but might be even more difficult since columns wouldn't be the same width, even for a smaller area. PDF isn't an option since this has to be interactive. Each of the labels such as ACC01 is clickable so our operations staff can see what is in that space.

Comment: @JimPowers For an example, I did a report with similar different sized columns in each row [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKHR6.png). That report is 6 Tablixes and took a long time to match it to the requirement. The key is just making extra columns and merging them as necessary.  The other workaround would be to put a rectangle inside the tablix cell and resizing/adding border to the rectangle inside the cell.  A lot of work, but workable.

Comment: Nice looking report! I did do a limited test on a different building's floor plan using a tablix and it worked. I took this floor plan with a ruler and red pen and drew a grid on the top where it made most sense for each column. I'll add the elements today and see what happens. Thank you for the feedback!